# Numba JIT on numpy.where and as.type

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm trying to use JIT to speed up some functions in my code using nopython mode. This works mostly but throws up errors in the following functions:

```
@jit (nopython =True)
def calc_density(pos, ncells, L):
    dx = L/ncells
    pos = pos/dx
    #plower = pos.astype(np.int)
    plower = np.int_(pos)

    offset = pos - plower
    opp_offset = 1- offset
    density = zeros((ncells),dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(0,ncells):
        ind = where((plower == i),dtype=np.float64)
        density[(i+1)%ncells] += sum(offset[ind])
        density[i] += sum(opp_offset[ind])

    density *= float(ncells) / float(len(pos))
    return (density)

@jit (nopython =True)
def periodic_interp(y, x):
    ny = len(y)
    if len(x) > 1:
        y = array(y) # Make sure it's a NumPy array for array indexing
    xl = floor(x).astype(int) # Left index
    dx = x - xl
    xl = ((xl % ny) + ny) % ny  # Ensures between 0 and ny-1 inclusive

    return y[xl]*(1. - dx) + y[(xl+1)%ny]*dx
```

In the first function I got the zeros part to work but this does not work for the np.where part.
The error for the first function is long but states:
[1] During: resolving callee type: Function()

For the second function the error is:

```
  File "C:\Users\Knowhow\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\typing\npydecl.py", line 433, in _parse_nested_sequence
    raise TypingError("%r not allowed in a homogenous sequence" % typ)

TypingError: array(float64, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogenous sequence
```

Can anyone suggest solutions to these, even if it means rewriting the function without the np.where.
Many Thanks.

Full code below:
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    #
    # Electrostatic PIC code in a 1D cyclic domain

```
from numpy import arange, concatenate, zeros, linspace, floor, array, pi
from numpy import sin, cos, sqrt, random, histogram, where, sum
import numpy as np
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Matplotlib plotting library

try:
    import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec  # For plot layout grid
    got_gridspec = True
except:
    got_gridspec = False

# Need an FFT routine, either from SciPy or NumPy
try:
    from scipy.fftpack import fft, ifft
except:
    # No SciPy FFT routine. Import NumPy routine instead
    from numpy.fft import fft, ifft
from numba import jit, int64


def rk4step(f, y0, dt, args=()):
    """ Takes a single step using RK4 method """


    k1 = f(y0, *args)



    k2 = f(y0 + 0.5*dt*k1, *args)
    k3 = f(y0 + 0.5*dt*k2, *args)
    k4 = f(y0 + dt*k3, *args)

    return y0 + (k1 + 2.*k2 + 2.*k3 + k4)*dt / 6.

#@jit("f8[:](f8[:],u1,f4)")
#@jit (nopython =True)
def calc_density(pos, ncells, L):


    dx = L/ncells
    pos = pos/dx
    #plower = pos.astype(np.int)
    plower = np.int_(pos)

    offset = pos - plower
    opp_offset = 1- offset
    density = zeros((ncells),dtype=np.float64)



    for i in range(0,ncells):
        ind = np.where((plower == i))

        density[(i+1)%ncells] += sum(offset[ind])
        density[i] += sum(opp_offset[ind])

    density *= float(ncells) / float(len(pos))


    return (density)
#@jit (nopython =True)
#jit("f8[:](f8[:], f8[:])")
def periodic_interp(y, x):


    ny = len(y)
    if len(x) > 1:
        y = array(y) # Make sure it's a NumPy array for array indexing
    #xl = floor(x).astype(int) # Left index
    #d=(np.int64(p))
    xl = np.int_(floor(x))
    dx = x - xl
    xl = ((xl % ny) + ny) % ny  # Ensures between 0 and ny-1 inclusive



    return y[xl]*(1. - dx) + y[(xl+1)%ny]*dx


def fft_integrate(y):
    """ Integrate a periodic function using FFTs
    """
    n = len(y) # Get the length of y

    f = fft(y) # Take FFT
    # Result is in standard layout with positive frequencies first then negative
    # n even: [ f(0), f(1), ... f(n/2), f(1-n/2) ... f(-1) ]
    # n odd:  [ f(0), f(1), ... f((n-1)/2), f(-(n-1)/2) ... f(-1) ]

    if n % 2 == 0: # If an even number of points
        k = concatenate( (arange(0, n/2+1), arange(1-n/2, 0)) )
    else:
        k = concatenate( (arange(0, (n-1)/2+1), arange( -(n-1)/2, 0)) )
    k = 2.*pi*k/n

    # Modify frequencies by dividing by ik
    f[1:] /= (1j * k[1:]) 
    f[0] = 0. # Set the arbitrary zero-frequency term to zero

    return ifft(f).real # Reverse Fourier Transform

def pic(f, ncells, L):
    """ f contains the position and velocity of all particles
    """

    nparticles = len(f)//2     # Two values for each particle
    pos = f[0:nparticles] # Position of each particle
    vel = f[nparticles:]      # Velocity of each particle

    dx = L / float(ncells)    # Cell spacing

    # Ensure that pos is between 0 and L
    pos = ((pos % L) + L) % L

    # Calculate number density, normalised so 1 when uniform
    density = calc_density(pos, ncells, L)

    # Subtract ion density to get total charge density
    rho = density - 1.

    # Calculate electric field
    E = -fft_integrate(rho)*dx

    # Interpolate E field at particle locations
    accel = -periodic_interp(E, pos/dx)

    # Put back into a single array
    return concatenate( (vel, accel) )

####################################################################
#@jit("f8[:],f8[:](f8[:], f8[:],f8,u1,f8[:], f8[:], f4)")
def run(pos, vel, L, ncells=None, out=[], output_times=linspace(0,20,100), cfl=0.5):

    if ncells == None:
        ncells = int(sqrt(len(pos))) # A sensible default

    dx = L / float(ncells)

    f = concatenate( (pos, vel) )   # Starting state
    nparticles = len(pos)

    time = 0.0
    for tnext in output_times:
        # Advance to tnext
        stepping = True
        dt = cfl * dx / max(abs(vel))
        while stepping:
            # Maximum distance a particle can move is one cell

            if time + dt >= tnext:
                # Next time will hit or exceed required output time
                stepping = False
                dt = tnext - time
            #print "Time: ", time, dt
            f = rk4step(pic, f, dt, args=(ncells, L))
            time += dt

        # Extract position and velocities
        pos = ((f[0:nparticles] % L) + L) % L
        vel = f[nparticles:]

        # Send to output functions
        for func in out:
            func(pos, vel, ncells, L, time)

    return pos, vel

####################################################################
# 
# Output functions and classes
#

class Plot:
    """
    Displays three plots: phase space, charge density, and velocity distribution
    """
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, ncells, L):

        d = calc_density(pos, ncells, L)
        vhist, bins  = histogram(vel, int(sqrt(len(vel))))
        vbins = 0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])

        # Plot initial positions
        if got_gridspec:
            self.fig = plt.figure()
            self.gs = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4)
            ax = self.fig.add_subplot(self.gs[0:3,0:3])
            self.phase_plot = ax.plot(pos, vel, '.')[0]
            ax.set_title("Phase space")

            ax = self.fig.add_subplot(self.gs[3,0:3])
            self.density_plot = ax.plot(linspace(0, L, ncells), d)[0]

            ax = self.fig.add_subplot(self.gs[0:3,3])
            self.vel_plot = ax.plot(vhist, vbins)[0]
        else:
            self.fig = plt.figure()
            self.phase_plot = plt.plot(pos, vel, '.')[0]

            self.fig = plt.figure()
            self.density_plot = plt.plot(linspace(0, L, ncells), d)[0]

            self.fig = plt.figure()
            self.vel_plot = plt.plot(vhist, vbins)[0]
        plt.ion()
        plt.show()

    def __call__(self, pos, vel, ncells, L, t):
        d = calc_density(pos, ncells, L)
        vhist, bins  = histogram(vel, int(sqrt(len(vel))))
        vbins = 0.5*(bins[1:]+bins[:-1])

        self.phase_plot.set_data(pos, vel) # Update the plot
        self.density_plot.set_data(linspace(0, L, ncells), d)
        self.vel_plot.set_data(vhist, vbins)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.05)

class Summary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = []
        self.firstharmonic = []

    def __call__(self, pos, vel, ncells, L, t):
        # Calculate the charge density
        d = calc_density(pos, ncells, L)

        # Amplitude of the first harmonic
        fh = 2.*abs(fft(d)[1]) / float(ncells)

        #print ("Time:", t, "First:", fh)

        self.t.append(t)
        self.firstharmonic.append(fh)

####################################################################
# 
# Functions to create the initial conditions
#

def landau(npart, L, alpha=0.2):
    """
    Creates the initial conditions for Landau damping

    """
    # Start with a uniform distribution of positions
    pos = random.uniform(0., L, npart)
    pos0 = pos.copy()
    k = 2.*pi / L
    for i in range(10): # Adjust distribution using Newton iterations
        pos -= ( pos + alpha*sin(k*pos)/k - pos0 ) / ( 1. + alpha*cos(k*pos) )

    # Normal velocity distribution
    vel = random.normal(0.0, 1.0, npart)

    return pos, vel

def twostream(npart, L, vbeam=2):
    # Start with a uniform distribution of positions
    pos = random.uniform(0., L, npart)
    # Normal velocity distribution
    vel = random.normal(0.0, 1.0, npart)

    np2 = int(npart / 2)
    vel[:np2] += vbeam  # Half the particles moving one way
    vel[np2:] -= vbeam  # and half the other

    return pos,vel

####################################################################

def main():
    average_time = []
    for i in range(1):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        L = 4.*pi
        pos, vel = landau(10000, L)


        s = Summary()

        run(pos, vel, L, 10, [s], linspace(0.,30,75))

        end_time = time.perf_counter()

        time_difference = end_time - start_time



        average_time.append(time_difference)


    print ("Average time is", np.round(np.mean(average_time),2), "+/-", np.round(np.std(average_time),2))

main()
```

Comment: What are you testing this on?

Comment: how do you mean? Using Spyder in Windows.

Comment: We can't help you without a [mcve]

Comment: Edited with full code

Comment: The code work except for adding @jit(nopython=True) for the two functions mentioned